# Show XML in tabular format

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a small tool.  It will take in as input various xml strings.  What I would like to do is transform that xml (which we can assume is well-formed) into a tabular format.

My first thought was to use the WPF DataGrid.  I tried something like the below:

```
string xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
            <Movies xmlns="""">
              <Movie Name=""Seven Samurai"" Id=""101"" Director=""Akira Kurosawa"">
                   <Comment Value=""1""/>
              </Movie>
              <Movie Name=""Happy Together"" Id=""102"" Director=""Wong Kar Wai"">
                   <Comment Value=""2""/>
              </Movie>
              <Movie Name=""Shoot The Piano Player"" Id=""103"" Director=""Francois Truffaut"">
                   <Comment Value=""3""/>
              </Movie>
              <Movie Name=""Roshomon"" Id=""104"" Director=""Akira Kurosawa"">
                   <Comment Value=""4""/>
              </Movie>
              <Movie Name=""Dead Man"" Id=""105"" Director=""Jim Jarmusch"">
                   <Comment Value=""5""/>
              </Movie>
              <Movie Name=""Children of Heaven"" Id=""106"" Director=""Majid Majidi"">
                   <Comment Value=""6""/>
              </Movie>
            </Movies>";

var sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(sr);
_dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

This will populate the data grid but it will only show the parent  rows.  The  child elements do not appear.  This is because those elements are put into another table of the dataSet (dataSet.Tables[1]).

All I need is a read-only display of the xml in a tabular format.  Some sorting/filtering ability would be nice but I don't know how (or if it is possible) to somehow place all the tables in the DataSet in a DataGrid in a sensible parent-child format.

I don't know the format of the xml in advance so I am looking for a solution that is as generic as possible.

Maybe DataGrid is not the ideal control for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if the DataGrid supports it, but you might try adding a relationship between the two tables to see if the DataGrid then shows it in a parent-child format.  Otherwise you may need to manually denormalize the data (which would be a simple Linq query).

Comment: @DStanley I see.  I guess I could add a relationship but this was only an example.  I would not know in advance the types of xml I would be using as input so it doesn't seem like I can add these relationships when necessary in a generic fashion (unless I am missing something).

Answer (score 0):

You can use xslt transformation to iterate through the nodes to convert into a table format

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a sample of how I can do this, maybe using the example xml in the original post?